# How to update code when summarise_each() and funs() are depreciated

Tags: r, list, dplyr, summarize, across

I wrote this piece of code a while ago and am now getting the below warning messages when I run it:

```
    group_by(ID) %>%
    summarise_each(funs(if (is.numeric(.))
      mean(., na.rm = TRUE)
      else
        first(.)))
```

> Warning messages:
> 1: `summarise_each_()` was deprecated in dplyr 0.7.0.
> Please use `across()` instead.
> This warning is displayed once every 8 hours.
> Call `lifecycle::last_lifecycle_warnings()` to see where this warning was generated.
> 2: `funs()` was deprecated in dplyr 0.8.0.
> Please use a list of either functions or lambdas:

> Simple named list:
> list(mean = mean, median = median)

> Auto named with `tibble::lst()`:
> tibble::lst(mean, median)

> Using lambdas
> list(~ mean(., trim = .2), ~ median(., na.rm = TRUE))

I have tried to update the code based using across() and list() but I cannot get it to work. Any ideas of how this code should be correctly updated?

Thanks

Comment: `summarise(across(where(is.numeric), ~mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE)), across(~where(is.numeric), first))`

Comment: `summarise(across(everything(), ~if(is.numeirc(.x)) mean(.x, na.rm=TRUE) else first(.x)))`